# What is the internal air pressure of a wrapped (with micro holes) food product heated in a microwave oven if I know how much steam is generated

Tags: fluid-dynamics

1. Food product is in a sealed wrapper, with 44 laser cut holes of 150 micron. (0.7mm sq hole area total).
2. When heated, product generates 2.2l of steam over 15 seconds. (33ml/sec)

How do I calculate the maximum internal air pressure inside the wrapper during the steam escape to see whether it exceeds the bursting pressure for the wrapper seals?

Comment: I guess a necessary CFD calculation would not be worth the effort. Just creating a prototype and trying it out would be much cheaper. After all, the answer also critically depends on the elasticity of the wrapper foil (thickness, material), widening of the holes due to pressure, etc. etc.

Comment: Hi Oliver, smallest run to get a trial will cost me just over £7000. If I take a risk. it may be a write off. In practice, knowing the seal bursting pressure, I really want to determine number of 150 micron holes required to vent without exceeding bursting pressure, but  keeping holes to a minimum to minimise freezer burn during storage. Wrapper has negligible elasticity and any pressures significant enough to widen the holes would burst the wrapper seal first so can be discounted.

Comment: Okay, then what about treating all holes equally and calculate the pressure drop of one hole as a function of mass flow current. I am not an expert in this, but either you find an analytic formula for an outlet in a plane wall or you use some software. One nice free tool I have used in the past is HydrauCalc (https://www.hydraucalc.com/). AFAIK you need to select the outlet geometry and parametrize it to your needs. However, I am not familiar enough with it to know its limitations. At least it computes the Reynolds number, so it can't be a completely naive approach.

Comment: But this is only the static part of the computation. With steam generation, you would need to solve the differential equation of mass outflow versus mass generation (evaporation). Maybe with simulink, or whatever the free counterpart in Scilab or so is.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for thoughts on this. I think I have resolved it. The web site below gives the formula for calculating air flow through an orifice. Knowing the external pressure as 1 bar, orifice size of 0.7mm and rate of steam generation 33ml/sec the formula gives me the internal pressure. (1.3bar)which is within the seal burst tolerance.

Formula is at - https://www.tlv.com/global/UK/calculator/air-flow-rate-through-orifice.html?advanced=on#